# mavenDeployer - artifacts How to add filename after version

Tags: gradle, maven-plugin, artifacts

I have :

```
 version = '0.2.0'


 uploadArchives {   
 artifacts {        
  archives file: someZipTask.destFile, name: 'com.testing.buil.test', type: 'zip', builtBy: zipInjectDll_32
 }
 repositories {
  mavenDeployer {           
    repository(url: repositoryBaseURL+'/Trash') 
   authentication(userName: artifactory_user, password: artifactory_password)
     }
    }
  }
 }
```

and finaly I need file name in artifactory with merged : com.testing.buil.test + $version + someZipTask.destFile.name, in the folder $version. How to do it ?

I tried to add to the version someZipTask.destFile.name, but the folder was also changed to the $version + someZipTask.destFile.name

regards 
Chris

Answer (score 0):

The directory and file names in Artifactory follow the Maven repository layout, and are a function of three coordinates:

- `groupId`: Typically set via `project.group` in Gradle.
- `artifactId`: Typically set via project name in Gradle (in `settings.gradle`), or via `project.archivesBaseName`, or via the archive name configured for a particular archive task (`someZipTask.baseName` etc.).
- `version`: Typically set via `project.version` in Gradle.

If you follow these guidelines, the `artifacts` block can be simplified to:

```
artifacts {
    archives someZipTask
}
```

`com.testing.buil.test + $version + someZipTask.destFile.name` doesn't follow the Maven repository layout, and you can't really have such a name in Artifactory (when used as a Maven repository).